# Clojure: How to prevent a process from running forever?

Tags: clojure

Basically, I am trying to generate `n` number of random number and use them as indices to return elements in the the sequence `(range n)` and I also want to keep adding them up on the fly by using `reduce`. 
The first 2 expressions return results relatively quickly. However, the 3rd expression takes forever to run, which I have no idea why. Does this have anything to with **laziness**, which is a concept that I never understand. If it does, please also elaborate on what laziness really means.

```
(reduce + (map #(nth (range 1000) %) (repeatedly 1000 #(rand-int 1000))))
504750
 (reduce + (map #(nth (range 10000) %) (repeatedly 10000 #(rand-int 10000))))
50334424
(reduce + (map #(nth (range 100000) %) (repeatedly 100000 #(rand-int 100000))))
;; this takes forever
```

And is there way to make sure the third line of expression return a definite answer without hanging in there forever ?

Comment: Have you tried to run this for a few minutes?

Comment: Also, **laziness** is a concept that the value should be computed when it's needed, and is super useful in Clojure, especially in infinite seqs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few mistakes here.

`(range n)` returns a sequence, `nth` function gives *indexed* access to collection.
Of course sequence doesn't know anything about index, so your `nth` works in `O(n)` time
To make `nth` a linear solution, transform seq to vector `(vec (range n))`

Every time to access an item in a collection you create a new range, what is not optimal.

Your 2nd case:

```
(time  (reduce + (map #(nth (range 10000) %) (repeatedly 10000 #(rand-int 10000)))))
"Elapsed time: 4055.15506 msecs"
```

Improved version:

```
(time(reduce + (let [array (vec (range 10000))] 
                 (repeatedly 10000 #(nth array (rand-int 10000))))))
"Elapsed time: 5.134413 msecs"
```

Comment: @Chinegro sequences in clojure are implemented as [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28abstract_data_type%29). So, there is now way to get `n`th element without traversing the whole sequence from the first element to the `n`th (`O(n)` complexity). On the contrary, vectors are implemented as indexed structures, so you could access `n`th element almost immediately (`O(1)` complexity).

Comment: Interestingly http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1515 could make this particular example faster.